# SVG вписывание symbol в блок

Tags: css, css3, svg

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переназначенный символ SVG вписать в блок с нужными размерами ? Приведу простой пример

```css
.home_page .logo_link {
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, 70%);
  width: 290px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.logoBuble_white {
  fill: #fff
}

.logoBuble_harlequin {
  fill: #f00
}

.bl_businessInfo__logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 29px;
  width: 112px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo_link" aria-label="" href="/">
    <svg id="logoBuble" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 290 250" width="290" height="250">

                            <symbol id="logoBuble_logo">

                           
                            <symbol id="netgament_element">
                                <path class="logoBuble_harlequin" d="M145.1 9L190 54.4l-44.8 45.4-44.9-45.4L145.1 9z"/>
                              
                            </symbol>

                            <use xlink:href="#netgament_element" x="0" y="0"/>
                            <use xlink:href="#netgament_element" x="101" y="85" transform="scale(0.77)"/>
                            <use xlink:href="#netgament_element" x="-13" y="85" transform="scale(0.77)"/>

                            </symbol>

                            <use xlink:href="#logoBuble_logo" x="0" y="0"/>
                        </svg>
  </a>


</header>

<footer class="footer" roll="contentinfo">


  <div class="bl_businessInfo">
    <a class="bl_businessInfo__logo" href="/">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <use xlink:href="#logoBuble_logo" x="0" y="0"/>
                    </svg>
    </a>
  </div>


</footer>
```

Есть SVG логотип в шапке сайта, как сделать его копию в подвале, но что б она вмещалась в блоке bl_businessInfo__logo с width=112px ? Я не понимаю, почему происходит смещение, пробовал и width=100% для потомка задавать и ещё всякие хитрости c viewBox="0 0 112 94", но пока не получается решить.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Задать `viewBox` & `width` атрибуты для `<svg>..</svg>` в `footer`'е, а вообще желательно для вложенного элемента ссылки передавать ширину относительно родителя с помощью `inherit`:

```css
.home_page .logo_link {
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, 70%);
  width: 290px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.logoBuble_white {
  fill: #fff
}

.logoBuble_harlequin {
  fill: #f00
}

.bl_businessInfo__logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 29px;
  width: 112px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo_link" aria-label="" href="/">
    <svg id="logoBuble" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 290 250" width="290" height="250">
      <symbol id="logoBuble_logo">
        <symbol id="netgament_element">
          <path class="logoBuble_harlequin" d="M145.1 9L190 54.4l-44.8 45.4-44.9-45.4L145.1 9z"/>
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#netgament_element" x="0" y="0"/>
        <use xlink:href="#netgament_element" x="101" y="85" transform="scale(0.77)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#netgament_element" x="-13" y="85" transform="scale(0.77)"/>
      </symbol>
      <use xlink:href="#logoBuble_logo" x="0" y="0"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
</header>
<footer class="footer" roll="contentinfo">
  <div class="bl_businessInfo">
    <a class="bl_businessInfo__logo" href="/">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="112" viewBox="0 0 290 250">
        <use xlink:href="#logoBuble_logo" x="0" y="0"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Опачки! Решили всё-таки остаться?